# Runtime switching between datasets in Tensorflow from_generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a huge dataset (about 50 Gigabytes) and I'm loading it using Python generators like this:

```
def data_generator(self, images_path):
    with open(self.temp_csv, 'r') as f:
        for image in f.readlines():
            # Something going on... 
            yield (X, y)
```

The important thing is that I'm using a single generator for both training and validation data and I'm trying to change the **self.temp_csv** during the runtime. However, things are not going on as expected and by updating the variable **self.temp_csv** which is supposed to switch between train and validation sets, **with open** is not called and I end up iterating over the same dataset over and over again. I wonder if there is any possibility to use **Dataset.from_generator** and during the runtime, I switch to another dataset to do the validation phase. Here is how I am specifying the generator. Thank you!

```
def get_data(self):

    with tf.name_scope('data'):

        data_generator = lambda: self.data_generator(images_path=self.data_path)

        my_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator=data_generator,
        output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
        output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None]), tf.TensorShape([None]))
        ).batch(self.batch_size).prefetch(2)

        img, self.label = my_data.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        self.img = tf.reshape(img, [-1, CNN_INPUT_HEIGHT, CNN_INPUT_WIDTH, CNN_INPUT_CHANNELS])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a reinitialize iterator or a feedable iterator to switch between 2 datasets as shown in the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator).

However, if you want to read all the data you have using the generator, then create a train and validation split, then its not that straightforward.

If you have a separate validation file, you can simply create a new validation dataset and use the iterator like shown above.
If thats not the case, methods such as [skip()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#skip) and take() can help you split the data, but the shuffling for a good split is something you need to think about.